# Progress Bar for Online Web Form

Tags: html, xhtml

I am making a application form for a survey of sorts, and want to include a progress bar at the top showing graphically (not really high end) how far the user has got.

I've spent a while surfing the net and asking Google in various ways to do this but it all comes out with progress bar for upload/download.

I am writing  the form in XHTML and CSS with a PHP handler to a MySQL Database. The general thinking seems to be ASP (a few are JQuery)to which I have no experience, if it needs to be ASP then fine, but is there any other way and if it does need to be ASP can you please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the application form look like? Several pages and the progress represents the number of the current page? Please define what the 'prgress' should be (maximum+current status)

Comment: Status, like percentage of the form. It's a application form made up of between 6-9 XHTML pages.

Comment: what's the problem then? just make 6-9 images with a different progress bar stage each and display 6-9 in the form pages...can be done with html alone, no need for php or asp or jquery...

Comment: If they only answer certain questions on each page per say, then it wouldn't be accurate to give them a percentage that isn't based on what they have done. Not a static image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Include another image on each page, showing the progress.
2. Use php to get the current progress and include the image.
3. Make a div as a progressbar with different width
4. ...

You could even just use simple html... However, here are two possible solutions with php:

```
<?php
$progress = 1;
$max = 5

echo "<img src=\"progress_".$progress.".jpg\" />"

?>
```

where progress_1.jpg, progress_2.jpg,... are your images.

Without images - just CSS:

```
<?php
$progress = 70;
$max = 100;
?>
    <div style="height:15px; width:<?=$max?>px; background-color:silver; padding:1px;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width:<?=$progress?>px; background-color:yellow"></div>
    </div>
```